# GlassFish can't start because of "port conflict" but nothing is using that port -- what's wrong with GlassFish?

Tags: unix, glassfish, port, macos

I develop on Mac (Lion) with Eclipse and GlassFish 3.1. GlassFish uses ports 8080 and 4848. Suddenly when I try to launch GlassFish it tells me it can't because there's a port conflict.

As far as I can tell, nothing is using that port. I shutdown everything and restart the Mac and still get the same error when I run GlassFish. I uninstalled GlassFish, deleted all the directories, restarted my machine, reinstalled GlassFish and same problem.

I created a new test user on my Mac, log out as me, log in as him, install GlassFish under that users account and it runs fine there.

It's like there's something in my user account that makes my Mac or GlassFish think that port is in use.

Does anyone know how I might solve this problem? I hate the idea of having to create a new account on my Mac and transfer all of my data there. Seems like an excessive solution.

Any ideas?

Rob

UPDATE: Doing a "lsof -i :8080" shows me this:

```
$ lsof -i :8080
COMMAND   PID    USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
launchd   158 stephen    8u  IPv4 0xffffff8014945fa0      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
launchd   158 stephen   10u  IPv6 0xffffff8014941240      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
printerAg 232 stephen    5u  IPv4 0xffffff8014945fa0      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
printerAg 232 stephen    6u  IPv6 0xffffff8014941240      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
```

I guess that means there is something on port 8080?  If so, what are launchd and printerAg?  And why are they running on this user account, but not on the new user account I created?  Thanks!

Comment: How exactly did you check if the port was in use?

Comment: I ran some commands my UNIX knowledgeable co-worker suggested, but apparently I didn't do it correctly.  See the update in the question, there appears to be something there.  Any idea what it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check who is using the port:

```
lsof -i :8080 -i :4848
```

Comment: Hi Rob, Ran the command and there appears to be something running (see the update I added to the question).  Any ideas what I should do next?

Comment: launchd is the main daemon-running system. You've installed some piece of software that is listening on 8080. See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html

Comment: Looks like I found it.  The task was called "printerAg" so I uninstalled/removed all the HP and printer related utilities and it looks like the task using 8080 is now gone.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also change the port of HP printers from 8080 to 18089 by the following command:

```
sudo sed -i "" -e "s|8080|18089|g" ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.hp.printerAgent.plist
```

Then restart you system.